# GDAL (CentOS 8) Install Failing

Tags: python, linux, gdal

For the best part of today, I've been trying to get my head around how to install GDAL on my CentOS 8 server.

I've researched on many different answers and solutions across different sites and across StackOverflow and nothing seems to be working! (I'm probably missing something obvious somewhere)

I'm trying to install GDAL using the command `pip3 install gdal`

Which in return, produces the following error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ydh0zt_x/gdal_e96fd73bd85b4e338f6c0fb234dcfaf1/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ydh0zt_x/gdal_e96fd73bd85b4e338f6c0fb234dcfaf1/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-wx20mgo0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.6m/gdal
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ydh0zt_x/gdal_e96fd73bd85b4e338f6c0fb234dcfaf1/
    Complete output (28 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying gdal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying ogr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying osr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying gdalconst.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdal_array.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdalconst.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/ogr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    copying osgeo/osr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/osgeo
    running build_ext
    Could not run gdal-config!!!!
    building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I../../port -I../../gcore -I../../alg -I../../ogr/ -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I. -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/extensions/gdal_wrap.o
    extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2813:10: fatal error: cpl_port.h: No such file or directory
     #include "cpl_port.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ydh0zt_x/gdal_e96fd73bd85b4e338f6c0fb234dcfaf1/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ydh0zt_x/gdal_e96fd73bd85b4e338f6c0fb234dcfaf1/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-wx20mgo0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.6m/gdal Check the logs for full command output.
```

So far, I've installed:

- Proj 6
- GEOS
- epel-release (For CentOS 8)
- gdal-libs
- PowerTools (I've also enabled powertools)

The error I've spotted within the output from above is `cpl_port.h: No such file or directory` and I have crosschecked this error across other forums, who have advised to run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev`

and

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
```

And finally, running the `pip3 install gdal` command.

Although, since I'm running CentOS 8, I don't have access to `"apt-get"` and instead have tried using `"Yum"` but haven't had any luck with getting the above proposed solution to work.

Would anyone be able to suggest or recommend any methods of resolving the `cpl_port.h: No such file or directory` error on a CentOS 8 server?

Many thanks! :-)

Comment: Can you try `yum install gdal-devel` and retry the `pip` command? That's in EPEL

Comment: Hello @jakub, Thank you for your response :-) I've just tried this and I get the following result: `Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Mon 07 Jun 2021 20:09:54 UTC.
Error: 
 Problem: package gdal-devel-3.0.4-7.el8.x86_64 requires gdal-libs(x86-64) = 3.0.4-7.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libpoppler.so.78()(64bit) needed by gdal-libs-3.0.4-7.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)`

Comment: Perhaps try using `--nobest` like the error suggests.

Comment: Thanks @jakub, still getting a similar error here when running the command with `--nobest` - Here's the error now (Nothing much has changed) - `Last metadata expiration check: 0:15:37 ago on Mon 07 Jun 2021 20:09:54 UTC.
Error: 
 Problem: package gdal-devel-3.0.4-7.el8.x86_64 requires gdal-libs(x86-64) = 3.0.4-7.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libpoppler.so.78()(64bit) needed by gdal-libs-3.0.4-7.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)`

Comment: Update: I have managed to install `geos-devel` through running the following commands: `yum install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm` and `yum install geos-devel` - Although when running `pip3 install gdal` I'm still getting the original error within my original post above (But I'm still getting the same error within my previous comment when I try to run `yum install gdal-devel`

Comment: You will want to see which package provides `cpl_port.h`. `geos-devel` might but not sure.

Comment: »» `#include "cpl_port.h"` «« : There is no /usr/include/cpl_port.hcpl_port.h , there is `/usr/include/gdal/cpl_port.hcpl_port.h` , from gdal-devel → The `epel.repo`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Hello! Thank you for your response :-) I have the latest version of EPEL installed. I don't have any folder called "gdal" within `usr/include/`

Comment: Seems you have non compatible "extra repo's"  . That's why you cannot install the default `gdal + gdal-devel` from EPEL. Please disable or delete the conflicting repo's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with CentOS
https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=18213

`gdal` requires `poppler-0.67`, which is missing from official repositories.
It is however present in the `raven-extras` repo:
https://centos.pkgs.org/8/raven-extras-x86_64/poppler-0.67.0-22.el8.x86_64.rpm.html

Or you can download it as is (arbitrarily named `poppler0.67.rpm` here) and use it when installing `gdal`.

```
curl -o poppler0.67.rpm https://pkgs.dyn.su/el8/extras/x86_64/poppler-0.67.0-22.el8.x86_64.rpm
yum install -y gdal poppler0.67.rpm
```

Update: the bug seems to be resolved https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1950024

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Ah, I have tried both solutions you have provided. If I try to install the RPM directly through the link you have provided, I receive the following output: `# dnf --enablerepo=raven-extras install poppler
Error: Unknown repo: 'raven-extras'`

Comment: Ah I've finally got this working with your second solution! I had to make a little alteration to the command from `yum install -y gdal poppler0.67.rpm` to `yum install -y gdal poppler0.67.rpm --allowerasing` - The `--allowerasing` flag cleared up the package conflictions! But it seems like GDAL is finally installed! Thank you so much for your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

For Centos 8 steam gdal installation steps i have solve dependences problem with below command.

```
dnf install --enablerepo=powertools gdal
```